# Python googleapiclient list all users in my Google Workspace - what is "my_customer"?

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I am trying to get a list of all users in my Google Workspace using Python. When I log on to https://admin.google.com and go to Directory -> Users I get a list of my users. I only have one organization.

What I am trying to do: List all accounts in my Google Workspace

Problem: When I run the code I get:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
> https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&maxResults=10&orderBy=email&alt=json
> returned "Invalid Input". Details: "[{'message': 'Invalid Input',
> 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid'}]">

**My code:**

```
"""
Google User Fetcher
File: src/google_user_fetcher.py
Updated: 30.09.2022

Fetches users from Google

"""

from __future__ import print_function

import json

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


class GoogleUsersFetcher:

    # - Init ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        service = self.service_account_login()
        if service == "-1":
            print("GoogleUsersFetcher :: Could no login to API")
        else:
            # Call the API
            print("GoogleUsersFetcher :: Welcome to the API")

            self.list_users(service)

    # - Login to service account -------------------------------------------------------
    def service_account_login(self):
        """
        Reads service-key.json and logs into Google API
        :return: service (Service key of type googleapiclient.discovery.Resource)
        """
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly']

        service_account_info: dict = json.load(open('_tmp/service-key.json'))

        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
            service_account_info, scopes=SCOPES)
        service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
        print(f"GoogleUsersFetcher :: Service OK {service}")
        return service

    # - List all users -----------------------------------------------------------------
    def list_users(self, service):
        print("Getting the first 10 users in the domain")
        results = service.users().list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=10,
                                       orderBy='email').execute()
        users = results.get('users', [])

        if not users:
            print('No users in the domain.')
        else:
            print('Users:')
            for user in users:
                print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(user['primaryEmail'],
                                          user['name']['fullName']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GoogleUsersFetcher()
```

I am thinking it may have something to do with the method `service.users().list`. It asks for 'my_customer' however I dont have any customers. I only have employees working in my organization.

```
results = service.users().list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=10,
                                           orderBy='email').execute()
```

Comment: Is this issue fixed for you ? I am also getting same issue